# SQL Server FileStream in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

How to use file streams in Entity Framework? I know it does not support file stream, so I decided to go around with just RAW SQL, **just for files**.

First, I tried to run custom script, ok:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql(@"
            CREATE TABLE FileStreams
            (
                Id BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                RowId uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT NEWID(),
                Stream VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM DEFAULT(0x)
            )
        ", true);
    }
```

It didn't work out, cause even though PRIMARY file group exist and IT IS DEFAULT, SQL Server just ignores this and spew out this:

> Default FILESTREAM filegroup is not available in database

Ok, I tried to create file group myself and make it default:

```
        Sql(@"
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.filegroups where name = 'FileStreamGroup') 
            BEGIN
                ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
                    ADD FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup
            END
        ", true);

        Sql(@"
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.filegroups where name = 'FileStreamGroup') 
            BEGIN
                ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
                    MODIFY FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup DEFAULT
            END
        ", true);

        Sql(@"
            CREATE TABLE FileStreams
            (
                Id BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                RowId uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT NEWID(),
                Stream VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM DEFAULT(0x)
            )
        ", true);
```

But, duh, it didn't work out and spew out this:

> Cannot change the properties of empty filegroup 'FileStreamGroup'. The filegroup must contain at least one file.

Why the heck does it need files is question out of my league. I just want to create table for storing big files and come across exception in which it tells me to create those files first - *BTOOM!*

So, here comes a reasanoble question - is it even possible to do that now? Because of every answer here on SO, and in the internet it just seems pretty dead feature. As if no one uses this and answers is just too old.

Comment: @rene we are not talking about **that** filegroups

Comment: Have a look at the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/create-a-filestream-enabled-database - the provided **filename** for the group is not really a file but a dictionary

Comment: Is there a way to add this 'dictionary' by local (not absolute) path? I want it to be easy deployable.

Comment: Try this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128657/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-File-Stream

Comment: I think this is not what I need. I want this to be from code as much as possible. Without need for anyone to manualy configure entire database.

Comment: Ask for the path during setup process

Comment: And you can store files in a varbinary(max) column without using FileStream or File Table.  Why do you want the files stored outside the database?

Comment: Because I want advantages of direct stream reads. It obviously greater for large files (files are ~ 20 mb).